# Comet with uwsgi and nginx, how to turn off the output buffer?

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, buffer

How can I prevent Nginx from buffering the output of my uwsgi app? For my comet style application I'm using long polling and the requests are now buffered.

I tried to reduce the size of the buffers, but I'm not allowed to put `uwsgi_buffer_size` and `uwsgi_buffers` on 0. Also `uwsgi_max_temp_file_size` does not work (eventhough the manual suggests that).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Until a few minutes ago this was not possible. nginx would always buffer all uwsgi and scgi responses, and no configuration would change that.

I have [submitted a patch for nginx](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,213388) (and it was accepted) and from the next version on there are two methods to disable buffering for uwsgi requests:

- put `uwsgi_buffering off` in the nginx config
- send a [`X-Accel-Buffering`](http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel#X-Accel-Buffering) 'no' header in the **response**

uwsgi never buffers the response, so no configuration is required on that end.

Comment: 10 years later! The X-Accel-Buffering is an excellent solution! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the uwsgi-embedded http-router/load-balancer directly ? It does no-buffering expecially for comet/websockets app. You can use nginx for static files mapping them to another domain.

Comment: In that case I could also http proxy the requests through nginx, as for proxying there are specific buffering flags. The thing I'm doubting is that uwsgi http server is able to give me a good performance and security.

Answer (score 0):

Try with uwsgi_max_temp_file_size = 0

Comment: As I wrote in the question, this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx "proxy" module has a directive for that, it's called [`proxy_buffering on|off`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_buffering), which does exactly what you want, it turns buffering off and proxies upstream output synchronously. But AFAIK neither FastCGI nor UWSGI modules have it.

BTW even when `proxy_buffering` is `off`, you may notice small delays because of OS TCP stack buffering.

Comment: Indeed, if I would use proxy_pass then this would be useful. But as I mentioned I use uwsgi so this does not work.

Comment: Ok, I'll tell you plainly: there is no solution.

Is downvoting your motivation for people? Good luck.

Comment: Please don't take the downvote personal. A downvote means "This answer is not useful". So I downvoted it as it was not useful to me, because it does not give an answer to my question.